# Node js sem framework, conferir código

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando trabalhar com nodejs sem framework para ter uma ideia mais detalhada de como funciona o node.

Esse código é o seguinte: eu faço uma requisição no banco de dados e passo o resultado para a renderFile poder enviar o objeto para a página, e assim poder estilizar a página com os dados do banco de dados.

Tem algum problema nesse código?

É uma forma errada seguir por esse caminho, sem utilizar nenhum framework?

```
function onFunction(req,res){
    con.query('SELECT * FROM barbeiro', function(err,result,fields){
        ejs.renderFile('./index.ejs',{data: result},(err,html) => {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
            res.write(html);
            res.end();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Não, não é errado seguir esse caminho, hoje muitos pseudo-desenvolvedores (e eu me incluo em certos casos) partem direto pra um framework, antes de dominar a ferramente, no seu caso o nodejs é a ferramenta, e um Angular, Ember, Vue, React seria o framework

Comment: To estudando node e to meio desconfiado de tudo que venho fazendo. Eu já utilizei o Express e funciona muito bem, eu só não me sinto a vontade de não entender o que acontece por baixo.

Comment: Uma dica pessoal, aprenda bem os fundamentos de js, os paradigmas disponíveis pela linguagem, pegue algumas libs que estão disponíveis no npm e acrescente no seu projeto para brincar, leia a respeito do typescript e de ecmascript 6|7|8 e só depois parta para um framework mais consolidado.... O caminho para dominar bem o js e o node hoje em dia é bem longo, se começar com um framework direto pode bater muito a cabeça.

Comment: Eu tinha um problema em entender como funcionava uma callback, eu não entendia como eu mandar um função me trazia os req e o res, até ver um video no youtube que mostrou como aplicar uma callback. Mais uma pergunta, vc falou com paradigma, vale a pena programar javascript com oo?

Comment: Não encontrei nenhum erro grosseiro no código. Não acredito que seja uma maneira errada de estudar, inclusive indico a todos os desenvolvedores tentar desenvolver alguma aplicação de estudos sem framework, por que com isso você consegue entender melhor o funcionamento do node.